# Obter o caminho de um arquivo dentro do projeto em forma de string

Tags: c, diretório

Estou usando um método que nos parâmetros dele eu informo um caminho de uma imagem, Exemplo:

```
Meu_Metodo("image\\test.png");
```

Só que essa imagem esta dentro de `Resources`, como podem observar nessa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu faço para obter o caminho dessa imagem dentro dos meus recursos "em forma de `string`"

Answer (score 0):

Se teu arquivo está na raiz do projeto e a imagem em uma pasta:

```
Meu_Metodo("Resources/Image1.png");
```

Comment: Kkkkkk irei fingir que não li isso

Comment: Sério que depois de compilado vai funcionar?